# RavenDb Studio does not restrict access

Tags: ravendb, ravendb-studio

I have a website hosted in IIS and RavenDb is running as a service on another box. The WebSite is running an application pool as a domain service account user.

I am trying to restrict all access to the Raven server such that only users in a domain user group can have any access to to Raven Studio. I have successfully seen Raven throw a 401 response from the the website code when I used a local machine account. All other access to the Raven server via Raven Studio has been permitted no matter what I've tried.

I have RavenDb build 2750 and the license status is Commercial Standard.

The RavenDb.Server.exe.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="Raven/Port" value="8080"/>
    <add key="Raven/DataDir" value="D:\data\Raven.Data\System"/>
    <add key="Raven/Authorization/Windows/RequiredGroups" value="Raven_Administrators_Group" />
    <add key="Raven/AnonymousAccess" value="None" />
 </appSettings>
    <runtime>
        <loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true"/>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <probing privatePath="Analyzers;Plugins"/>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

The example above is one of dozens of iterations or trial and failures so far. The Raven_Administrators_Group is a local machine group on the box where the Raven server is running. There are no members that have been added to that group.

The Raven/Authorization/WindowsSettings document looks like this at the moment:

```
{
  "RequiredGroups": [
    {
      "Name": ".\\Raven_Administrators_group",
      "Enabled": true,
      "Databases": [
        {
          "Admin": true,
          "TenantId": "*",
          "ReadOnly": false
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "RequiredUsers": []
}
```

I have tried many different combinations of things.

It is unclear weather or not the Raven.Bundles.Authoriztion.dll bundle must be in the plugins folder or not.

It is unclear weather or not the Raven.Server.exe.configuration is independent of the Raven/Authorization/WindowsSettings document settings.

Comment: Are you trying to access with a machine or domain admin?

Comment: Machine accounts do fail as expected but all domain accounts are allowed through regardless if it is added to a the Required Users or Required Groups.

Comment: Are you using _domain admins_ ?

Comment: Unknown, still verifying that. I am not a domain admin as far as I know yet and I have access. I am an Administrator on the box how ever. I have positive results from web server to Raven server. I just haven't seen a failure path yet for someone directly hitting the Raven Studio. Still testing.

Comment: Okay is now known. I am not a Domain Admins but being and Admin on the box seems to be the reason RavenDb is showing up. I do now have a positive test failure from someone not in either group and Raven Studio does load but show a 403 error popup and does not display the databases.

Comment: @Mike Can you answer your own question with the last comment?